# Eclipse VIews frozen on a specific class

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to have eclipse freeze its view on a specific class regarding the Outline view and/or other views when you navigate and write code in the other window?
I want to have a quick reference of a class when I am going to use it's API from a third one. And I don't want to open second instance of eclipse or take a picture for that.
Does anyone know any trick ?

Comment: The Outline always shows the active file. You can split the editor area to show multiple files

Comment: probably but that is not what I am thinking. I have many classes to popup and edit, search for a keyword and then apply changes based on the API of a third class. So I hoped there is a plugin that does exactly what I am asking. Open the class API as quickview, and have it there pinned.